# Deleting from RealmSwift.List<Object> raises out of bounds exception

Tags: ios, swift, database, xcode, realm

I have been trying to follow the ListSwiftUI example provided by the Realm Swift team. It has been working very well for me but I have run into a problem, when I try to delete from a `RealmSwift.List<Object>` the app crashes with an exception `"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Index 5 is out of bounds (must be less than 5).'"`

Model:

```
final class Todo: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @objc dynamic var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var createdAt: Date = Date()
    
    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        "id"
    }
}

final class Todos: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id: Int = 0
    
    let todos = List<Todo>()
    
    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        "id"
    }
}
```

SceneDelegate.swift

```
let realm = try! Realm()
var todos = realm.object(ofType: Todos.self, forPrimaryKey: 0)
if todos == nil {
    todos = try! realm.write { realm.create(Todos.self, value: []) }
}

// Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
let contentView = ContentView(todos: todos!.todos)
```

ContentView.swift

```
@ObservedObject var todos: RealmSwift.List<Todo>
var body: some View {
    ForEach(todos) { (todo: Todo) in
        Text("\(todo.name)")
        .onDelete(perform: delete)
}

func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
    if let realm = todos.realm {
        try! realm.write {
            realm.delete(todos[offsets.first!])
        }
    } else {
        todos.remove(at: offsets.first!)
    }
}
```

I have checked the count of my todos list and the db in Realm Studio, it actually contains the index 5. And this crash is not specific to only index 5, e.g. if I only have 2 items in the list, the app crashes with `Index 1` or when it contains 5 items, it crashes with `Index 4`.

The example has pretty much the same Data Models and it works perfectly. So what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that by deleting a `todo` from your `todos` list swiftui is unable to reconstruct the change in the `ViewGraph` because the record is clearly not there anymore. By first deleting the record and then removing it from your `todos` list swiftui rerenders the view because of the change in the `@ObservedObject` property. Try the following:

1. Try updating your realm version to the latest version. Currently at `5.4.0`. They have added support for Combine/SwiftUI. See: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Enums/Publishers.html for a list of publishers. By using the latest version you have the possibility to use the following publishers:

   - `objectWillChange`  - Publishes void each time the collection or the object changes
   - `publisher` - Publishes the collection each time it changes
   - `changesetPublisher`  - Publishes a RealmCollectionChangeset each time the collection changes or if used on a realm object it publishes the changes of that object
   - `objectWillChange` - Publishes void every time the object changes
   - `freeze()` - Freezes the collection or the object and makes it immutable.
2. `freeze()` your `todos` collection by using `ForEach(todos.freeze())`. By freezing the collection SwiftUI is able to do the "rendering" check.

Another approach would be to subscribe to the listed publishers and react accordingly to their changes.

Comment: I am already using the latest version and I get the mistake I was making. But using freeze() in the ForEach throws another exception "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Object is already managed by another Realm. Use create instead to copy it into this Realm.'". I am looking into this further.

Comment: Try to use one single realm instance for your operations.

Comment: Yup its certainly an issue with creating new Realm instances. Can you recommend a good method to pass around the same instance of Realm between different views so that I can access different Models from different Views rather than instantiating them all at once in the SceneDelegate? Something like CoreData's environment context maybe?

Comment: Yeah there are a lot of approaches. The simplest answer to that is to use the singleton pattern. Just create a class and add the following property: `static let shared = Realm()`. Then you can use it via `SomeClass.shared`

Comment: Thanks for all the help!